# Can't make sense of the meaning of a paragraph

Tags: meaning, translation, phrases

I am trying to read a reading of a 8 year old and I cannot seem to get any sense of it no matter how hard I try. Can someone translate *and also explain* to me the meaning of this? (I understand *all the words* though)

> 石たちは、おたがいに口をきこうともせず、じっとおしだまっていましたが、それは、体の中をいたみがゴソゴソ歩き回っている足音や、悲しみが、ぬらぬらとはいまわる気配に、じっと耳をすましているからでした。

I am understanding that the stones are quiet and don't even try to talk to each other,
and then *something* about some "foot steps of the pain roaming around their bodies(??) but I completely lose it with the [ぬらぬらとはいまわる気配に、じっと耳をすましているからでした。]

I have no idea how these all make sense

by the way, The reading continues with

> 「今日のお日さまは、あたたかいな。光のうずが、シャブシャブ言っている。ほら。」
> スミレは、またしゃべりだしました。たとえ、返事がなくとも自分のおしゃべりが、何の楽しみもない石たちのただ一つのなぐさめになっていることを、よく知っていたからです。
> 「聞こえるでしょう？　光が流れてくる音が。」

but I can guess the sense of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up to それは, your understanding is fine.

The overall structure is それは...じっと耳をすましているからでした *It was because (stones) carefully listened to ...*.

The phrases in between are what stones listened to:

- 体中をいたみがゴソゴソ歩き回っている足音や *the footsteps of the pain roaming around their bodies and*
- 悲しみが、ぬらぬらとはいまわる気配 *the sensation of the grief crawling around*

Note the verb はいまわる（這い回る）.

Obviously both are weird per se, but I suppose those would make sense if you read on the story.